# Mist: error no data is deployed on this contract address

Tags: solidity, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When creating a new contract via `deploy new contract` (in Mist on the Test-Net), I get the error  "**No data is deployed on this contract address**", but I filled in every field. it is a very easy straight forward contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;
contract MyContract {
 string public userName;
 function MyContract (string _name) {
   userName = _name;  
 }  
}
```

It compiles without any problem, I can select the contract and I can add the constructor parameter (`_name`), I can deploy it and send it, but then I get that data error and the contract doesn't appear in my custom contracts overview. I already tried setting `select fee` on faster, this didn't help, unfortunately.

Anyone having any an idea what this could be? Thanks in advance or your help!

Comment: Please tell the version of Mist you are using, will try to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried replicating your contract on **Ethereum Wallet 0.8.9**. Everything seems good, the contract is deployed and mined properly. 
There may be an issue with Ethereum-Wallet version, try updating your wallet. One user had the same issue [see here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12379/problem-publish-ethereum-contracts).

Comment: Thanks Prashant. I'll give it a try. (as far as I know I installed the latest version.) The data that you put in the _name string field was published just fine?

Comment: Yes, the data was published fine. It worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to send more gas at the testnet than normally needet.
You can adjust it in the screen where you have to put in your password while your are deploying your contract.
[image]

As you see the estimated fee consumtion is higher then the maximum of provided fee, even though ive selected the fee for the fastest transaction

Comment: Yeah it seems like a bug in the ethereum wallet code, thanks for the answer this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have constructor with modifier and try just copy and paste this code.

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract JustDebug {
    address owner;
    string greeting;

```
function JustDebug(address _owner) payable{ 
    //Конструктор
    owner = _owner; 
}


function kill() { 
    //Вернуть бабки
    if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); 
}


function greeter(string _greeting) public {
    greeting = _greeting;
}

function greet() constant returns (string) {
    return greeting;
}
```

}

[image]