# Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions

I don't understand why if i execute my function with web3.js i obtain this error in the transaction:

**Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]**

I read this other [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12447/deploying-a-smart-contract-displays-warning-bad-instruction) about the same error. I don't understand why with this code its happening the same:

```
contract Music is owned{

    string public themeMusic;
    string public idMusic;
    int public money;

    function Music (string setThemeMusic, string setIdMusic, int setmoney) {
        themeMusic = setThemeMusic;
        idMusic = setIdMusic;
        money = setmoney;
    }

    function setMoney(int moneyUpdate) onlyOwner {
        money = moneyUpdate;
    }
}
```

The error is with the setMoney function, is for the `onlyOwner`? i need to make it `payable` anyway? I don't want to make it `payable`, just only use it for set the money and this function only for the owned.

More information:

- I make other contracts with similar functions and don't have this problem.
- This contract is created by other contract like the typical example Factory.
- Owned is a contrac where i store the address and test if is the owner.
- I'm using `Meteor.js` and `Web3.js`.

**How do you interact with the contract?** For interact with the contract i'm using the Web3.js APi of ethereum.

**What command do you use**? I'm defining the contract with the ABI and the address of the contract like this `myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABIArray).at(contractAddress);` and then i call the function of the contract like this `myContract.setMoney(money);` (and the callback function).

**Do you use production blockchain?** I'm working in Ropsten Test-net.

**My Music company:**

```
contract musicCompany is owned {

    address[] public listofmusic;

    function addMusic(string setThemeMusic, string setIdMusic, int setmoney) onlyOwner {
        address newMusic = new Music(setThemeMusic, setIdMusic, setmoney);
        listofmusic.push(newMusic);
    }
}
```

This contract can create a new Music contracts.

**My Owned contract:**

```
contract owned {

    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

}
```

**My Web3.js code:**

```
'click .setMoney'(event, instance) {
     var price = document.getElementById('priceUpdate').value;
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("contract price");
     myContract.setMoney(price, function(error, result){
      if(!error)
          console.log(result);
      else
          console.error(error);
      })
```

Screenshot of the metamask transactions without any problem:

[image: Screenshot of the metamask transactions without any problem]

Screenshot of the EtherScan.io transaction with the error:
[image: Screenshot of the EtherScan.io transaction with the error:]

**Update 1:** I try using unsigned integers and bytes32 instead of int, the result is the same. *Maybe the problem is in the modifier, could it be?*

**Update 2:** I tried to delete the `onlyOwner`modifier of the function and doesn't work ...

**Update 3:** I tried to delete all the modifier, `is owned` and `onlyOwner` and still doesn't working. I think the problem is with the builder function, i will starting now to make test with it...

**Update 4:** By doing Test, i know that `moneyUpdate` have the value correctly and `money` the same, but I have discovered that the value of `money` don't change. And I have discovered too that when i print the result variable of my callback inside "My Web3.js code" i obtain the adress of the transaction `0x0fda5d31d02c87aa20c45a54f6859c7576b4f0aae4a639c47ec23e5c4e‌​3d9953`.  In principle, the transaction is performed but the error prevents the change.

Some transactions (all are mine) for view the error:

[0x52ef9164750c4e174cba1a5f45343220458f1cedca25380f0aaf102df0a8f895](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x52ef9164750c4e174cba1a5f45343220458f1cedca25380f0aaf102df0a8f895)

[0x4e00d9d67ffb906e0036434ea2e14acea82a6aabb4d8c99d94c0b2bcdef24f7a](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4e00d9d67ffb906e0036434ea2e14acea82a6aabb4d8c99d94c0b2bcdef24f7a)

[0x4663fa874993d54989d073f72d6846cae652a454349e62882dccc96d78528a8e](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4663fa874993d54989d073f72d6846cae652a454349e62882dccc96d78528a8e)

[0x69fbf54ffd81ee114efcd750d4e97bb528ecc868140abdecf218e9ae66391a5](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x69fbf54ffd81ee114efcd750d4e97bb528ecc868140abdecf218e9ae66391a5)

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the failing transactions?

Comment: yes you have one in the answer, but i can put more.

Comment: Generally, I recommend using the Truffleframework for development. https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle It eliminates many problems like these right away and helps you to get going more fluently.

Comment: @NikitaFuchs Yes, i know the framework, but this development started with meteor... Now I can't change or is there easy migration?

Comment: With truffle, you get promisified functions according to the function names in your contract, it doesn't get any simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is so obviously simple that the only problem would seem to be with onlyOwner. I would check the value of the `owner` variable. I bet it's not what you think it is. (It's either zero or the value of the sender who deployed the contract). You didn't provide the address of the contract, so I can't check the value of `owner` on Etherscan. Plus you're not providing the address of the calling account. If they don't match, the transaction will throw, which (as is true of all Ethereum errors) will report out of gas. If the code is really as simple as you say, the only possible problem is with `owner`. I would check that.

Comment: I will try it and then i comment something, i put some transactions on the question if you want check this.

Comment: I delete all reference to the owner class in this contract and  in the contract who created the music contract, and it works but if i put again it fail... What is happening?

Comment: During initialization the owner variable is either getting set to a account address different than the one you think it is, or it's not getting set at all (and is therefore zero). You should be able to tell by using the 'ReadContract' tab on etherscan.io.

Someone commented above that there was no constructor in your code which I would think means the 'owner' is zero.  What is the address? I can check it.

Comment: You need to provide the full source code for the contract, or a pointer to it via GitHub or something. If it works without the `isOwner`, and doesn't work with it, then the value of `owner` is not set to the msg.sender. (If you look at the owner contract you can see that `isOwner` only throws if the values don't match. The reason for this is because you're most likely not setting `owner`. Maybe I'm missing something. See the actual full source would help.

Comment: Yes i fixed it, with your tip the address set in 'isOwner' is not the same of the contract Music so when i use 'onlyOwner' modifier this don't work, cause this address is the parent contract. This fail makes me modify all the code a lot of times... for just a wrong address.

Comment: The `owner` gets set in the constructor using the `msg.sender`, which is the address of the account that deployed the contract. If you're calling into a function protected by `isOwner` later, and the address that is initiating that call is not the same as the one who deployed the contract it will throw an error. It sounds to me that you may have chosen to remove the `isOwner` which is maybe not the best idea. You should call from the proper owner otherwise you lose the protection that the `owned` contract provides. Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: No don't worry about isOwner, i'm testing for fix it the problem with the `isOwner` but my principal problem "Identify where the problem is here and why this happens" is solved. Now i have other problem with the addres who execute the function and why is not the same of the other.  I will put the last part of my code for if you have some idea that was is wrong with that.

Comment: Updated with last part of the contracts interaction, that's all. If you have some idea can answer me with a comment. (Maybe the problem was the creation of the contract, i'm testing now about it)

Comment: At this point I would suggest that you greatly simplify the question and ask a new question and they will get more answers from other people.

Answer (score 3):

Your transaction appears to be failing because you're calling it from a different address than you created it with.  I walked through the [first transaction](http://ropsten.etherscan.io/remix?txhash=0x52ef9164750c4e174cba1a5f45343220458f1cedca25380f0aaf102df0a8f895) and noticed that it was skipping an equals test (`ISZERO + JUMPI`) when comparing against the caller.  Sure enough, that transaction was sent from [`0x178597064fc55ea505c3ea066c154d92bc264943`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x178597064fc55ea505c3ea066c154d92bc264943), but the contract was created by [`0xc2351205ee14cdb8b61ffc826ad1906bc7c08755`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc2351205ee14cdb8b61ffc826ad1906bc7c08755)

So, as Thomas [posted](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/error-encountered-during-contract-execution-bad-instruction/17556#17556), the problem is indeed due to the `onlyOwner` modifier.

It would be helpful to see the code for the `owned` contract from which yours is inheriting.  I'd imagine it doesn't do much more than set `owner` to `msg.sender`, but there might be some additional complications in there.

Regardless, if you try sending from [`0xc2351205ee14cdb8b61ffc826ad1906bc7c08755`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc2351205ee14cdb8b61ffc826ad1906bc7c08755) to the contract in the first transaction, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to more details that would be nice (How do you interact with the contract? What command do you use?), you need to add a constructor function to the contract. Also, try using unsigned integers instead of int.

```
contract Music is owned{

    string public themeMusic;
    string public idMusic;
    int public money;

    function Music() {
    // this is the constructor, do something here or leave it empty
    }
    function Car (string setThemeMusic, string setIdMusic, uint setmoney) {
        themeMusic = setThemeMusic;
        idMusic = setIdMusic;
        money = setmoney;
    }

    function setMoney(uint moneyUpdate) onlyOwner {
        money = moneyUpdate;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry car is not the correct name of the function, car is the Music constructor, who is called for other function in other contract who generate the contracts. I fix it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works fine (I've put the `owned` part to the same file). I used `truffle` with `testrpc` (I wrote and run a JS test). Maybe the problem is how you deploy/interact with your contract.

Side note: function needs to be `payable` when you send Ether by calling it (you want to receive Ether by function invocation). Here you don't send **real** money, you just set the value.

Comment: I'm using `meteor.js` and this structure works fine in other of my contracts, with the same set function and the same functions of the `web3.js API`, and here when i execute this function ( cause only don't work this function, the others functions work's well) appear this error in etherscan and the transaction is not processed well so i can't change the money.

Comment: Are you sure that `price` you send to setMoney is an integer value? Have you tried with hardcoded value e.g. 10 ?

Comment: Hey Lukasz i try to hardcode the value, and happen the same, but when i use the Ethereum scan for view the transaction, i obtained in the data input the number but it is in hexadecimal thats is normal? like this:
 `[0]:000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a`

Comment: @Gawey I really don't know. Try the procedure below.
1. What does the callback function print out? 
2. Try to emit event (that will contain value of `money` and `moneyUpdate`) after setting the value and there capture the event in the browser and print it out.
3. Try to read the money value from contract. Maybe it's was updated and it's just Etherscan bug.
4. Do you use production blockchain?

Comment: for the 2) and 3) question all is well, `moneyUpdate` have the value correctly and `money` the same, but  I have discovered that the value of `money` don't change. For the 4) i 'm working in Ropsten test-net. For the 1) I have discovered that when i print the `result` variable of my callback inside "My Web3.js code" i obtain the adress of the transaction `0x0fda5d31d02c87aa20c45a54f6859c7576b4f0aae4a639c47ec23e5c4e3d9953`, some idea?  In principle, the transaction is performed but the error prevents the change.

Comment: No better idea for now. Just let me know when you fix it, I'm curious what was wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank you i will offer a bounty for the answer hahahaha