# Vote example from Solidity Docs doesn't work

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mist

I can't deploy the [voting example from docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html) and get error saying that 'No data is deployed on the contract address!'. I have no idea what goes wrong.

Comment: Welcome. Have a look over here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/mist-error-no-data-is-deployed-on-this-contract-address

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the fact that maximum provided fee was lower than estimated. After changing maximum fee in windows which asks you to type your password I successfully deployed contract.